# Using powershell to move azure runbooks and their webhooks to another automation account

Tags: azure, webhooks, azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook

So, as the title says ..
I have an Azure automation account with few runbooks and some of them can have webbhooks .. one or more

I use Powershell script to

- Create automation account - DONE, creted.

  ```
  New-AzAutomationAccount -Name $newAutomationAccountName -Location $location - 
  ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
  ```
- Supplying the name of the source automation and target automation account names, and resource group, I am creating run books by their respective names in the new AutomationAccount.  - DONE, I can see those created

  ```
  #Copy automation runbooks from source
  $runBooks = (Get-AzAutomationRunbook -AutomationAccountName $srcAutomationAccountName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName).Name
  $runBooks.foreach{
      Write-Host "Processing RunBook $_"

      #Create runbooks
      Invoke-Expression "$Workfolder\powershellScripts\createAzureAutomationRunBooks.ps1 - 
      resourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -location $location -srcAutomationAccountName 
      $srcAutomationAccountName -newAutomationAccountName $newAutomationAccountName - 
      Workfolder $Workfolder -runBookName $_"
  ```

I externalize the calls to create runbooks to separate script that seems straight forward,

> if( -not(Get-AzAutomationRunbook -AutomationAccountName
> $newAutomationAccountName -
> ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $runBookName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue))
> {
> Write-Host "Creating new Runbook $runBookName"
> New-AzAutomationRunbook -AutomationAccountName $newAutomationAccountName -Name
> $runBookName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Type PowerShell
> Start-Sleep -Seconds 5 #Wait some time for Runbook to settle succesfully
> }
> else {
> Write-Host "Updating Runbook $runBookName"
> Set-AzAutomationRunbook -AutomationAccountName $newAutomationAccountName -Name
> $runBookName -LogVerbose $True -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
> Start-Sleep -Seconds 5 #Wait some time for Runbook to settle succesfully
> }

but they are created.
**However**, when i go to the new Automation Account and "Edit" the runbook I do not have any content in it.
Please, what is going on here?

Also, another question:
When in the similar manner I copy WebHooks from Original RunBooks, do their URL change?  If so, how can I obtain the new URLS?

Comment: There is a functionality to move runbooks from one automation account to another with the help of PowerShell script. But for webhooks we need to achieve it by a manual process. There is no built-in functionality existed for moving webhooks from one to another. @Dmitriy Ryabin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using PowerShell to move azure runbooks and their webhooks to another automation account: -

*After an analysis of all of your requirements, I've provided detailed answers to each of your queries.*

**1.**

It is possible to import content from one runbook to another runbook which is located in another automation account. To do that, use `Export-AzAutomationRunbook` and `Import-AzAutomationRunbook` PowerShell commands inside your source automation account and the script is given below.

```
connect-azaccount -identity
$sourceAutomationAccount = "newauto"
$DestAutomationAccount= "newauto1"
$resourceGroup = "xxxx"
$runbooklist = (Get-AzAutomationRunbook -AutomationAccountName $sourceAutomationAccountName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup).Name
foreach ($runbook  in  $runbooklist) {
Export-AzAutomationRunbook -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -AutomationAccountName $DestAutomationAccount -Name "xxx" -OutputFolder "C:\xxxx.ps1"
}
foreach ($runbook in  $runbooklist) {
Import-AzAutomationRunbook -Path "C:\xxxx.ps1" -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -AutomationAccountName $DestAutomationAccount -Type PowerShell
}
```

*Output:*

[image]

*After importing the source runbook into the target runbook under another automation account, I was able to view the same content.*

[image]

**2.**

When it comes to webhooks, there is no way to import and export them from one to another. Because webhooks always have a unique Url that is only visible at the time of webhook creation. After that, it is not visible to users for security reasons.

As a result, one must do it manually. If you want to add the same webhooks to the target runbook, create a webhook with the same name as the source runbook webhook and set it with the exact configuration as the source configuration, including the expiry time.

**3.**

> Do their URL change:

***Yes,*** webhook URLs are unique, and they will change even if you generate them with the same settings and name as existing ones.

> It is an unique address that a client calls with an HTTP POST to start the runbook linked to the webhook. It's automatically generated when you create the webhook. You can't specify a custom URL.

Reference [doc](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/automation/automation-webhooks.md) for more relevant information.

Comment: Thank you, very much.
This is so much more helpful than official documentation !! You actually help with understanding concept.  
I am just starting with Azure and am wondering, Is there a resource that I could use to learn the concepts about other parts in this way ?

Comment: The one thing I notice, there is no way to create a webhook in the automated way.  My ultímate goal is to devise a DevOps methodology for CI/CD pipelines deploying various Azure resources (DataFactory, Keyvaults, etc..) between various environments (Test/UAT/Prod).   My runbooks are to call particular ADF pipelines, and are to be called from webhooks in the 3rd party systems.  
This is why I was asking about moving or copying using powershell, since it is very flexible allowing doing it in the sequential way designed for my specific needs

Comment: You can follow MSDoc for all the Azure resources which is clearly explained. @DmitriyRyabin